# bx slider: don't run auto after move slides by finger

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a problem with bx slider when I move slides by my finger it stops and it will not moving again! Even when I try to move it using the buttons, it does not respond!

this is my js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var slider = $("#sli").bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 190,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 6,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 5,
            preloadImages: 'visible',
            auto: true,
            pause: 1000,
        });
        $('.bx-prev, .bx-next').click(function(e)
        {
            slider.stopAuto();
            setTimeout(function() {
                slider.startAuto();
            },3000);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

when I click the buttons it will start again moving slides,

so anyone can help me :(